# How can I make an histogram equalization using GLSL shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, histogram

I am a user of osgEarth (library for rendering terrain in 3D) and I want to use the GLSL (shader) code to make an histogram equalization for some specific images( very white and it need to be equalized).

How to do that in GLSL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, not by using an histogram equalization, but by using a linear stretching, here is an example for the GLSL code:

```
varying vec4 oe_layer_texc;
uniform sampler2D oe_layer_tex;
float NMIN = 0.0; 
float NMAX = 65535.0; 
float OMIN = 238.0; 
float OMAX = 557.0; 
float space = ( NMAX - NMIN ) / ( OMAX - OMIN ) ; 
float bins = ( OMAX - OMIN ); 
vec4 srcPixel =texture2D(oe_layer_tex, oe_layer_texc.st);
float value = srcPixel.x * 65535.0 - OMIN;
color.rgb = vec3(( NMIN + ( value * space ))/65535.0);
</glsl>
```

Comment: have you got a working version? The above good doens't seem to be working. Also ```bins``` isn't used anywhere.